# Escape loop after variable not nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want my barcode scanning app to stop scanning after it finds a result. This is my code:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:        (AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
NSString *detectionString = nil;
NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
        AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];

for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
    for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
        if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
        {
            barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
            highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
            detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (detectionString != nil)
    {

        NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://example.com/index.php?b=", detectionString]] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

        _label.text = connect;

        break;
    }
    else
        _label.text = @"Scan Barcode";
}

_highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect;

}
```

I basically want to send the barcode to my server via NSURL like i have below. Although currently it keeps sending multiple requests. I only want it to send the NSURL once then stop.

Comment: Please indent your code. Also it's too long, please remove details not related to the repeating upload

Comment: If i knew what was related to the repeating upload i would have solved it already.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on your `stringWithContentsOfURL:` call and then stepping through to see how your method keeps on looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So put your detectionString variable outside your function. Otherwise everytime you call that function detectionString is declared again and again.

```
@interface YourClassName ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *detectionString;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad{
   self.detectionString = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should move `NSString *detectionString = nil;` outside of the function so it doesnt get reset each time the method is called, and put a check before the for loop to make it not go into it if you have set the detectionString already